# Call a function after all ajax requests are done when using a foreach statement in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an `each` statement and inside it I call ajax to send some information to server.

```
$.each(array, function(k, v) {
   $.ajax({
       ...
   });
});
```

When **all** ajax requests are done then call a function here...
How to do that ?

I cannot use `async: false` flag anymore because it is deprecated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Store the promises returned by `$.ajax` in an array, and then use [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to wait for them all to complete:

```
var promises = [];
$.each(array, function(k, v) {
   promises.push($.ajax({
       ...
   }));
});
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
    // They're all done now
});
```

or using `$.map`:

```
$.when.apply($, $.map(array, function(k, v) {
   return $.ajax({
       ...
   });
})).then(function() {
    // They're all done now
});
```

You'll want to look at [`done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/), [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), and [`always`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) to determine which is best for your scenario.

`$.when`'s API is <s>a bit broken</s> designed for a slightly different use case, which is why we have to call it in that odd way. What it does is accept a bunch of promises as discrete arguments, and return a new promise that will be resolved when all of the promises you pass it are resolved. E.g.:

```
$.when(promise1, promise2, promise3).then(...);
```

But frequently we have an *array* of promises (such as in the above). Since it expects discrete arguments, we use `Function#apply` to call it, since `Function#apply` accepts an array and then calls the function with the entries from the array as discrete arguments.

**Note**: `$.when` *resolves* the promise it returns when **all** of the promises you give it are resolved, or *rejects* its promise when **any** of the promises you give it is rejected. So if one of the ajax calls fails, you'll get your callback right away, **even if other calls are still outstanding**.

If you don't want that, then you have to write your own function, which isn't hard; something a bit like this:

```
function waitForAll(promises) {
    var waitingFor = promises.length;
    var allGood = true;
    var oneResolved = oneSettled.bind(null, true);
    var oneRejected = oneSettled.bind(null, false);
    var d = $.Deferred();

    promises.forEach(function(promise) {
        promise.then(oneResolved, oneRejected);
    });

    return d.promise();

    function oneSettled(resolved) {
        if (!resolved) {
            allGood = false;
        }
        if (--waitingFor === 0) {
            if (allGood) {
                d.resolve();
            } else {
                d.reject();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That just waits for them all, and then either resolves or rejects depending on whether any of them failed. You could take it further, resolving or rejecting with an array of results.

---

You can make `$.when` with an array a bit more convenient by giving yourself a utility function:

```
function whenAll(array) {
    return $.when.apply($, array);
}
```

...and then:

```
whenAll($.map(array, function(k, v) {
   return $.ajax({
       ...
   });
})).then(function() {
    // They're all done now
});
```

You could even add that to `$`, but of course, a future version of jQuery may define `whenAll`, so be cautious.

Comment: @SnakeEyes: `then` providing multiple functions might be a better choice (if you provide just one function, `then` and `done` are the same thing), or `always`. You presumably do want notification even if one or more of the ajax calls fails.

Comment: @SnakeEyes: FYI, I just noticed that `$.when` rejects immediately when any of the promises you give it rejects, even if others are still outstanding. I've updated the answer to flag that up, and to give an alternative if you want to keep waiting for all of them even when one of them fails.

Comment: Ajax from `promises.push` is called so promise doesn't help me... I want to call ajax when I call apply methods.

Comment: @SnakeEyes: *"Ajax from promises.push is called so promise doesn't help me"* I don't know what you mean by that. You've said you want to get a notification when all the ajax requests are done. That's what the above does.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder I was having the same issue. $.when executing reject function if any async fails. I am maintaining a variable to check if all the ajax calls completes.